How do I handle redirects in ASP.NET MVC application that is embedded in iframe?
I have a small ASP.NET MVC application that needs to be embedded in another page via iFrame.
There are only 2 views on the same controller:
Home/Index
Home/Results/{id}

When a user inputs data in the index page, there is no problem. Data is stored in the DB and if there are validation errors, the view will load again with those errors listed for the user to correct.
However when trying to redirect to the Home/Results/{id} page after validating user input, I get an error:

An error occurred while processing your request

There is no error actually logged in my system or in console other than this.
Can a redirect be handled inside an iFrame using ASP.NET MVC, or am I missing something?
I tried adding this line to the global.asax.cs to disable the sameorigin X-Frame header:
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;

But it didn't fix the issue.
The app works as expected when accessed directly and not in an iFrame

This was not an issue with redirecting, it was an issue with Session / ViewData variables.  Apparently Session variables don't work in an MVC application that is hosted in an iFrame and cause a null object error.
